# SSRS - How to use a parameter that will determine if the other date parameter will be used to filter by delivery date or posting date

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters

I am creating an SSRS report the will be filtered by a date parameter.  However, i want to have an option for that Date parameter will be used to filter by Posting Date or Delivery Date

Answer (score 1):

A parameter for the DATE_TYPE needs to be created with the Posting or Delivery as the available values.

If you want to do the filter in SQL, you would add something like:

```
WHERE 1 = 1 
AND <CURRENT CRITERIA>
AND (POSTING_DATE = @DATE OR @DATE_TYPE <> 'Posting') --the parenthesis are VERY important here
AND (DELIVERY_DATE = @DATE OR @DATE_TYPE <> 'Delivery')
```

If the Date Type Parameter = Posting, the Posting Date must be the @DATE parameter. If it's not Posting then the second part of the OR will be True. Then it does a similar check on the Delivery Date field.

It's a little more complicated in the FILTER tab of SSRS's tables, charts or datasets.

In the Filter tab, add a new filter. Choose the Posting Date field as the Expression, date as the type and = as the operator. For the Value, press the Function button [Fx] to open the expression window. Your expression would be something like

```
=IIF(Parameters!DATE_TYPE.Value = "Posting", Parameters!DATE.Value, Fields!POSTING_DATE.Value)
```

The do the same for the Delivery date field.

This will compare the Posting date field to the date parameter if the DATE_TYPE is Posting. Otherwise it will compare the Posting date field to the Posting date field which will always be true when DATE_TYPE is NOT Posting.